# Não consigo chamar método imprimir () e passar a instancia da porta serial

Tags: c#

Em resumo:
esta variavel de objeto   **_serialPort** do `Form1` quero utilizar na Classe Imprimir e no outro Form:    **Config_Serial : Form**

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    static SerialPort _serialPort; //instancio o obj no load_form
```

tentei isso:

```
private void ConfigurarToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Config_Serial janela2 = new Config_Serial(this);
        janela2.ShowDialog();
```

Mas não consigo usuar a variavel aqui :

```
public Config_Serial(Form1 x)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        janela1 = x;
    }
```

Comment: isso está bem confuso *"se eu colocar publico não deixa"* como assim não deixa? cade o código do `Form1`? onde está usando o parametro `frm1`? Se recebe um `Form1` como paramentro, pq precisa instanciar um outro? Realmente está difícil de entender

Comment: **"se eu colocar publico não deixa"**. O que significa isso? Se o código apresenta mensagem de erro edite a pergunta e nos apresente a mensagem. Outra coisa esse fragmento não diz muita coisa, por exemplo você tem a linha: `Form1 instanciaDoForm1; //crio um objeto do tipo FORM 1, que será usado dentro da classe` , e em seguida faz `instanciaDoForm1._serial_serialPort.Write(result, 0,result.Length);` , do meu ponto de vista `instanciaDoForm1` é nulo e ultima linha vai dar erro. Então precisaríamos de mais código, não esquecendo as mensagens de erro.

Comment: tá tentando criar o método dentro do construtor da classe, aí não dá mesmo

Comment: @Lucas Miranda - Puts,  pode ser isso mesmo que passou batido.  Esta confuso porque tentei fazer uma forma, passando o form não deu, tentei passar pelo método, mas como estava com erro nada funcionou.
O que seria o mais correto neste caso, passar o form para a classe ou passar  a variavel de instancia da porta serial?

Comment: @GilceclerCarneiro o correto é editar a pergunta colocando um fragmento mais representativo da situação e apresentar as mensagens de erro para que a pergunta possa ser reaberta e nosso colega possa o responder adequadamente.